# expo start failed after SDK 45 upgrade - expo-keep-awake function could not be cloned

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, expo

expo start failed systematically after upgrading to SDK 45.

```js
iOS Bundling failed 4230ms
node_modules/expo-keep-awake/build/index.js: function (path) {
          return fn.call(state, path, state);
        } could not be cloned.
Error: function (path) {
          return fn.call(state, path, state);
        } could not be cloned.
    at Object.serialize (node:v8:333:7)
    at _default (/home/prince/Documents/HandyTradie/fromBucket/htMobile/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/util/clone-deep.js:22:34)
    at normalizeFile (/home/prince/Documents/HandyTradie/fromBucket/htMobile/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:84:36)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/home/prince/Documents/HandyTradie/fromBucket/htMobile/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:31:50)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/prince/Documents/HandyTradie/fromBucket/htMobile/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform-ast.js:26:41
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/home/prince/Documents/HandyTradie/fromBucket/htMobile/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
```

Note that I do not use expo-keep-awake directly, it is not linked in my package.json

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue after upgrade to `sdk 45`. This way is really work for me:

- Delete the file `yarn.lock`
- Delete the folder `node_modules`
- Run `yarn install`